# Symmetrization of pentadiagonal matrices

Tags: matrix-theory, similarity

Nonsymmetric tridiagonal matrices $T_3$ can easily be symmetrized via a (diagonal) similarity transformation $D=\text{diag}(d_1, \dots, d_n)$ (i.e. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Similarity_to_symmetric_tridiagonal_matrix))
$$
J_3=D^{-1} T_3 D \,.
$$

Is there a [similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) $P$ for [pentadiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix) matrices $T_5$ such that the transformed matrix 
$$
J_5 = P^{-1} T_5 P
$$ 
is symmetric? Possibly using a lower [bidiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidiagonal_matrix) matrix as $P$?

**Update:** As the Wikipedia article for the tridiagonal matrix $T_3$ points out it must be real and the product of offdiagonal entries must be strictly positive. Are there similar conditions that must hold for $T_5$?

Comment: crossposted, please don't do that, in order to avoid duplication of efforts --- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3450440/87355

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I couldnt find a guideline where this topic would fit better. Could you help? Which one should I delete?

Comment: this may well be on-topic here, but asking at the same time on different sites should be avoided, and in particular not disclosing the double posting is very much frowned upon.

Comment: Some conditions must be required on $T_3$ otherwise it's eigenvalues may be complex. Presumably also for $T_5$

Comment: @Icv I edited the question: I explicitly included the requirements on T_3.